# How to validate field when rendering same field multiple time with different name id in redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

Here i am having problem with validation,i wanted to render list of 5 items,where all the fields in list are same,below is the code

```
ListData = () => {
    let a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        a.push(<ListItemView value={i} key={i} />); // Component
    }
    return a;
};


render() {
    return (
     <div>
       <List>{this.ListData()}</List> // List of 5 items
       <Button disabled={this.props.disabledSubmission} 
        color="primary"type="submit">
        Invite Members
       </Button>
    )
}
```

> FieldComponent

```
 const ListItemView = ({ value }) => {
   return (
    <ListItem>

        <div className="col-12 w-100">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-5 col-12">
                    <Field
                        name={`${value}-name`}       // 0-name
                        component={renderTextField}
                        label="Name"
                        className="mt-1"
                        fullWidth
                        margin="normal"

                    />
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-12">
                    <Field
                        name={`${value}-email`}     // 0-email
                        component={renderTextField}
                        label="Email"
                        className="mt-1"
                        fullWidth
                        margin="normal"
                        type="email"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ListItem>
    );
 };
```

Problem is that when i try to validate with redux form i am confused that how to validate every field with it name - `0-name,0-email`,etc...

So,how i can check it with a loop or something that makes validation work for every field with statically write something like this

```
 const validation = (values) => {
  const errors = {};
  if(!values[`0-name`]) {
    errors.values[`0-name`] = 'Required'
  } else if(!values[`0-email`]) {
    errors.values[`0-email`] = 'Required'
  } 
  if(!values[`1-name`]) {
    errors.values[`1-name`] = 'Required'
  } ... // and many more...

   return errors;
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, You should have two separate pure functions one to validate Name and one to validate email. Like below.

```
<Field
                    name={`${value}-name`}       // 0-name
                    component={renderTextField}
                    label="Name"
                    className="mt-1"
                    fullWidth
                    margin="normal"
                    validate={validateName}

                />
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-12">
                <Field
                    name={`${value}-email`}     // 0-email
                    component={renderTextField}
                    label="Email"
                    className="mt-1"
                    fullWidth
                    margin="normal"
                    type="email"
                    validate={validateEmail}
                />
```

However, if you want the only function to do the job

```
const validate = (value, allValues, props, name) => {
if(name.includes('email')&& notEmail(value)){
return 'invalid email'
}
if(name.includes('name')&& notName(value)){
return 'invalid Name' 

}

return undefiend;

}
```